# Azure Automation: Parse WEBHOOKDATA with a python runbook

Tags: python-2.7, azure, azure-automation, azure-runbook

In azure automation, when you define a webhook for a runbook the headers of the request are passed to the runbook via the `WEBHOOKDATA` input parameter. For python workbooks, the parameter is passed as first argument to the script.

For example, here is a runbook:

```
import json
import sys

print(sys.argv)

if len(sys.argv) > 1 :
    test = json.loads(sys.argv[1])
    print(test)
```

Here is the input parameter `WEBHOOKDATA`

```
{"WebhookName":"python-Test-Arguments","RequestBody":"","RequestHeader":{"Cache-Control":"no-cache","Connection":"keep-alive","Accept":"*/*","Accept-Encoding":"gzip","Host":"s2events.azure-automation.net","User-Agent":"PostmanRuntime/7.1.1","action":"myaction","Postman-Token":"312ce179-d2d1-4b5d-935c-d801fc0ba114","x-ms-request-id":"e6b3a5e3-17b3-4d2a-a00c-a1be928acca2"}}
```

The output (basically `print(sys.argv)`)

```
['C:\\Temp\\yjzgss3j.git\\caf4e30b-0cb1-4c60-9e93-e2315b376634', '{WebhookName:python-Test-Arguments,RequestBody:",RequestHeader:{Cache-Control:no-cache,Connection:keep-alive,Accept:*/*,Accept-Encoding:gzip,Host:s2events.azure-automation.net,User-Agent:PostmanRuntime/7.1.1,action:myaction,Postman-Token:312ce179-d2d1-4b5d-935c-d801fc0ba114,x-ms-request-id:e6b3a5e3-17b3-4d2a-a00c-a1be928acca2}}']
```

`json.loads` fails

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Temp\yjzgss3j.git\caf4e30b-0cb1-4c60-9e93-e2315b376634",
line 7, in <module> test = json.loads(sys.argv[1].strip()) File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py",
line 339, in loads return _default_decoder.decode(s) File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py",
line 364, in decode obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end()) File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py",
line 380, in raw_decode obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)ValueError: Expecting property name: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
```

The JSON syntax looks correct to me. Might be something related to encoding, or how Azure automation pass the parameters to runbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually I think that your problem is a malformed JSON string. Notice that your string does not have quotes:

```
{WebhookName:python-Test-Arguments}
```

It should be something like this:

```
{"WebhookName":"python-Test-Arguments"}
```

To solve this you need to fix your response string. [This is a thread that talk about this kind of operation.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46976276/convert-string-without-quotation-marks-to-json-in-python)

Comment: Thank you. I used some regex to bring quotes back. And made an example on [repl.it](https://repl.it/@Ameb/AzurePythonRunbookWEBHOOK)