# Azure Runbooks - Parse Python Params

Tags: python, json, azure, azure-runbook

I have a runbook and I am trying to basically parse parameters I entering into the body of the POST request (using Postman). I looked at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49402149/azure-automation-parse-webhookdata-with-a-python-runbook), but couldn't get it to work.

My runbook's code where I am trying to get the params:

```
mode = str(sys.argv[1])
resource_group_name = str(sys.argv[2])
vm_name = str(sys.argv[3])
```

here's my Postman call:
[image: Postman]

Error message:

> in raw_decode obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)ValueError: Expecting
>   property name: line 1 column 2 (char 1)

Answer (score 1):

This is because when you pass the json from postman to runbook, the runbook will take the whole json string as one parameter, you can use `print(sys.argv[1])` to check this behavior. The output like below:

[image]

In your case, there is a workaround. When you get the input parameter, get this section after `RequestBody:`, this one: {"resource_group_name":"vv1","vm_name":"vv2"},which is a json string Then you can parse the json string, get the value you want.

Sample code as below:

```
import sys
import json

#view the input parameter
print(sys.argv[1])

input_str = sys.argv[1]

# use "1" in index() method, to ignore the first { symbol in the input parameter
start_str = input_str.index("{",1)

end_str = input_str.index("}",1)

str = input_str[start_str:end_str+1]

text = json.loads(str)#parse the json string

#check the value
print("resource_group_name: "+text["resource_group_name"])
print("vm_name: "+text["vm_name"])
```

Test result as below:

[image]

Comment: Hi, appreciate your feedback. But I am not sure how you got this to work. There's a few things:
- the first param with all info is at index ```0``` and not ```1``` (i.e. ```sys.argv[0]```)
- for me, even if I print index ```0```, ```1```, and so on - I don't get the desired output. It stops after like 20 characters... basically, after the first attribute I am passing in the body. 
- interestingly enough, when passing 3 params, I cannot get access to the third one. It won't print anything. 

Microsoft in the meanwhile has gotten back and recommended PowerShell based runbooks.

Comment: @DevKing, you can ask anything you want to know. It works at my side.

Comment: So, even if I take just your code and only print the argument, the output is this: ```{WebhookName:v2,RequestBody:\t{"Mode"``` not more... I will explore PowerShell runbook. Microsoft confirmed that something seems to be not working w/ Python runbooks. But thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar kind of of issue when creating an Azure Runbook in Python. It got invoked by a webhook. When testing the runbook with an Activity Log Alert, it invokes the runbook with a WEBHOOKDATA parameter that contains JSON in the  RequestBody.

Because Python runbooks do not support parameters the way PowerShell runbooks do, the WEBHOOKDATA string gets passed in as a long string. I found that the JSON payload of the RequestBody contains newlines (\r\n) which causes that each part after a newline is perceived as a new commandline argument. This results in the Runbook receiving a large number of commandline argument, each representing a part of the string. Quite messy.

I ended up creating this routine to handle it:

```
import sys
import json

def ExtractJsonRequestBodyFromWebhookdataArgument(args):
    """
    Python does not support named parameters (like PowerShell). The WEBHOOKDATA parameter will be passed in as
    one large string. But... the RequestBody sometimes contains an encoded json string. That will have
    special characters like \r\n or \" and then the parser does not understand it anymore.
    That's why there is a special routine to 
    """
    # Combine all separte commandline arguments into 1 large string.
    combinedArg=""
    for index in range(1,len(args)):
        combinedArg = combinedArg + args[index]

    # Extract the RequestBody
    # Find the opening { and then parse the remaining string to find the closing }
    requestBodyRaw=""
    bracketCounter=0
    for index in range(combinedArg.index("{",1),len(combinedArg)):
        requestBodyRaw=requestBodyRaw + combinedArg[index] 
        if combinedArg[index] == "{": bracketCounter += 1
        if combinedArg[index] == "}": bracketCounter -= 1
        if bracketCounter==0: break

    # Remove the unnecessary literal characters
    cleanRequestBodyString = requestBodyRaw.replace('\\r\\n','').replace('\\"','"')
    return json.loads(cleanRequestBodyString)

# Sample of Azure runbook in Python which is invoked in a Webhook.
try:
    jsonBodyJson = ExtractJsonRequestBodyFromWebhookdataArgument(sys.argv)
    print("schemaId = " + str(jsonBodyJson['schemaId']))
except:
    print("Payload has an invalid structure.")
```

Hope it helps.